# How do I add "and" before the last author's last name?

Tags: java

```
    public String Cite()
{
    String authorsList = "";
    Collections.sort(authors);
    for(Author a: authors)
    {
        authorsList += a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName + ", ";
    }

    String cite = authorsList + "\"" + title + "\", " + venue + "(" + getAcronym() + ")" + " , " + 
    publisher;
    return cite;     
}
```

How would I go about adding the word "and" to separate the last two names of the list?

Comment: Try using a `for` rather than `for each`. e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < authors.size() -1; i++)`. Iterate up until the last author.  Then, simply do `" and " + authors.get(authors.size()-1)`. You'll need to verify that the authors list is at least two authors.

Comment: That question is kind of its own answer: if you have a list of `n` authors, then you join everything up to n-1 with a comma, and then you add "and" followed by the final author. Right now you're joining all of them: stop short by one.

Comment: Use the for loop as suggested and be careful to manage the case in which you only have one author.

Comment: You can use the class `StringJoiner` or `Collectors.joining` to this purpose: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--

Comment: A joiner would add it to all where he only wants it on the last.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop with index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < authors.size(); ++i) {
    if (i == authors.size() - 2) {
        authorsList += a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName + "and ";
    } else {
        authorsList += a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName + ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Errors: 1) Compilation error: What is `a`? --- 2) With only one author, result is `"S. King, "` --- With 2 authors, result is `"S. Kingand J. Grisham, "` --- With 3 authors, result is `"S. King, J. Grishamand W. Shakespeare, "`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a normal `for` loop, so you can detect that you're on the first and/or last element.

Other changes:

- Remove the `,` after the last author.
- Use `StringBuilder` to build a `String`.

```
List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new Author("Stephen", "King"),
        new Author("John", "Grisham"),
        new Author("William", "Shakespeare"),
        new Author("Charles", "Dickens") ));
Collections.sort(authors);

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < authors.size(); i++) {
    Author a = authors.get(i);
    if (i != 0)
        buf.append(i < authors.size() - 1 ? ", " : " and ");
    buf.append(a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName);
}
String authorsList = buf.toString();

System.out.println(authorsList);
```

*Output*

```
C. Dickens, J. Grisham, S. King and W. Shakespeare
```

#### Oxford comma

Whether or not you want `,` comma before `and` (Oxford comma) is of course entirely up to you.

```
        buf.append(i < authors.size() - 1 ? ", " : ", and ");
```

*Output*

```
C. Dickens, J. Grisham, S. King, and W. Shakespeare
```

---

***UPDATE***

Since all 4 other answers at this time gave bad result for a single Author, here is test result for various number of authors.

#### Full Test

```
List<Author> allAuthors = List.of(
        new Author("Stephen", "King"),
        new Author("John", "Grisham"),
        new Author("William", "Shakespeare"),
        new Author("Charles", "Dickens") );
for (int aCount = 0; aCount <= allAuthors.size(); aCount++) {
    List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>(allAuthors.subList(0, aCount));
    Collections.sort(authors);

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < authors.size(); i++) {
        Author a = authors.get(i);
        if (i != 0)
            buf.append(i < authors.size() - 1 ? ", " : " and ");
        buf.append(a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName);
    }
    String authorsList = buf.toString();

    System.out.println(aCount + ": \"" + authorsList + "\"");
}
```

*Output*

```
0: ""
1: "S. King"
2: "J. Grisham and S. King"
3: "J. Grisham, S. King and W. Shakespeare"
4: "C. Dickens, J. Grisham, S. King and W. Shakespeare"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String Cite(ArrayList<Author> authors){
        String authorsList = "";
        Collections.sort(authors, new CustomComperator());
        int size = authors.size();
        int count = 0;
        for(Author a: authors) {
            if (size ==1) {
                authorsList = a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName;
            }

            else if (count == size-2) {
               authorsList +=  a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName ;
            }
            else if (count == size - 1) {
                authorsList += " and " + a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName ;
            }

            else{
                authorsList += a.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + ". " + a.lastName + ", ";
            }
           count ++;
        }
        return authorsList;     
    }
```

Comment: With 1 author, result is `" and S. King"`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the corner case. I updated the code.

Comment: You should remove the `println(size)` statement.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas

Comment: Ok, that works now, so down-vote removed. Although result is correct, it seems excessively repetitious, so no up-vote from me. Sorry.

Comment: @Andreas It's okey. It's also experienced programmer's responsibility to keep a high standard in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same without loops you could:

Define a `toString` or similar method inside your `Author` class:

```
class Author{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Author(String firstName,String lastName){
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s. %s",this.firstName.toUpperCase().charAt(0), this.lastName);
  }
}
```

And use the [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) to create the initial list (comma separated).

```
List<Author> authors = Arrays.asList(new Author("Jules", "Verne"),
    new Author("Pablo", "Neruda"), new Author("JK", "Rowling"));
authors.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.lastName));
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(
    authors.stream().limit(authors.size() - 1).map(a -> a.toString()).collect(
        Collectors.joining(" ,")));
```

And after that, add the last "and":

```
if (authors.size() > 1) {
  result.append(String.format(" and %s", authors.get(authors.size() - 1).toString()));
} else {
  result.append(authors.get(authors.size() - 1).toString());
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**: `P. Neruda ,J. Rowling and J. Verne`